# SQLDeveloper copy data from one database to a different user in another database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement where I want to copy the data from a table called SCHEDULE in a database to the same table in a different database using SQLDeveloper.

In destination, the SCHEDULE table shows under a different user (CLIENT_READER). I am connecting to the destination DB using the username = APP_READER which has the permission to access the SCHEDULE table which is under the **other users** list.

Other users -> CLIENT_READER -> TABLES -> SCHEDULE

I am trying to do this via the **Database Copy** tool.

When I apply the database copy tool, it doesn't report any error but simply skips the copy

```
Copy Option: Objects Copy
Source Connection: TAXI_DEV_1
Destination Connection: TAXI_QA_1
DDL Objects:
Tables
Data Objects:
Tables
COUNTRY
Copy DDL: No
Copy Data: Yes
Append Existing Objects
--- START --------------------------------------------------------------------
Skipping SCHEDULE
--- END --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help me do the copy, please?

Comment: does the user APP_READER, which looks for the name that it does not, permissions to write in the destination schema. You would need `insert any table` or specific `grant insert into schedule to app_reader`. It looks for the name that you are using a user with read privileges,  not writing ones.

Comment: the database copy tool tends to skip steps instead of producing errors for exceptions that it is not able to handle properly.

Comment: I tried manually inserting a record in to the same table in destination by logging in as APP_READER and I was able to insert it. So I assume it does have write permission.

Comment: you need more than SELECT privs on a table for the copy to work - I believe. Can you run the Copy as user that owns table SCHEDULE ?

Comment: I have all priviledges to the user. (SELECT, INSERT, DELETE)